# how to call a function as user click on search in alert view iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

//---------Searchoing----- //

```
- (IBAction) Search_hadit 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:@"Search"
                      message:@" "
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Search",
                      nil];


    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(14, 35, 255, 23);
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
    myTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    myTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Query";
    myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
    myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;// use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
    myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right
    [alert addSubview:myTextField];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

When I click search button in my app alert view show...
I want when user click search button I get the text which he enter and send this data to another function on as he click search button where I can perform search. Any idea?

Comment: can u elaborate your problem? The description that you have given is insufficient to answer.

Comment: sir i want when user click on my search button an alert view is show and he entre a qury and as he touch on search .. a function call where i can pass the query as well .. got it ?

Comment: @mahes where do u chnge ples mention

Comment: Give 4 spaces before every line of your code and when you write in a loop, give 4 more spaces and so on. You can always have the preview of what you are typing down under.

Comment: @mahes unable to understand wht are u saying :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess (acording to the title) you'll need an UIAlertViewDelegate or at least the function:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

   NSString* buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
   if ([buttonTitle equalToString:@"Search"]) {
      [do something];
   }
}
```

But the text in your description describes a different problem than your title. I can't provide a solution to that, though.

Comment: how this function will call??

Comment: im new to iphone environment :(

Comment: Copy my code to your controller file and set alert.delegate = self. Maybe you can try to solve your other problem with the UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: - (IBAction) Search_hadit {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
        initWithTitle:@"Search"
        message:@" "
        delegate:self 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
        otherButtonTitles:@"Search",
        nil];
   alert.delegate = self;}     then i write ur code n add UIalertviewdelegate as weel